# Array of objects set to 'active' in Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, ng-class

I have a listing of items utilizing `ng-repeat`

Object

```
var items = [{"name": "item1"},
 {"name": "item2"}...
];
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="addItemToCollection(item)">
  {{item.stuff}}
</div>
```

addItemToCollection simply takes which one was selected and adds or splices it into a different array with some logic applied to either allow it or deny it so I end up with something like:

```
var selectedItems = [{"name": "item15"},
 {"name": "item26"}...
];
```

How would I bind this new array to an **active** class on the original array, that is if **item3** and **item5** were clicked, set a class of 'active' on both of them?

ie:

```
{{item1.stuff}}
{{item2.stuff}}
{{item3.stuff}} // (has class active based on 2nd array)
{{item4.stuff}}
{{item5.stuff}} // (has class active based on 2nd array)
```

where:

```
selectedItems = [{"name": "item3"},
 {"name": "item5"}...
];
```

What would be the best way to set up an `ng-class` on my `ng-repeat` declaration to reflect this?

Comment: Do you need the second array? Wouldn't it be easier to simply add a "selected" property to the types contained in the original array and perform the same logic before setting this value? That way, you could use ng-class to accomplish what you're looking to do.

Comment: Trying to think of the broader scope. Essentially there will be multiple `selectedItems` states and the initial array is simply the data source. The 2nd array acts as a unique, fully enclosed area of all the data I'll need for each area that has the items that were selected during a prior state.

Comment: You'll probably have to explain your problem a bit more. Still don't see the need of the second array.

Comment: The use-case is a deck selection. The initial array is all of the cards available, and all of the data that could possibly exist for those cards. The 2nd array is the cards that were selected which are placed into a separate array so that I don't have to traverse the hundreds of cards every time I want to call something such as {{card.cost}} or {{card.name}}. I want to be able to use the 2nd array, say if I had a deck saved and wanted to edit the deck, to show which cards were selected out of all of the available cards.

Comment: The point is, most views will have no need to use the other 200 cards that are in the data-set, just the 8 that are selected. By creating a new array of just the cards that exist in the deck, most views in the app will be minimal and easy to traverse, but in the one view where I want to be able to add/remove cards from the deck I need a larger set of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to just add a class for each addition to the `selectedItems` array is to user to following code:

```
<!-- toggle class with active field -->
<li class="list-group-item"
  ng-repeat="item in items"
  ng-class="{'active': active}"
  ng-click="active = toggleSelect(item)"> <!-- set active field on select -->
  {{ item }}
</li>
```

As you can see I've used a `toggleSelect` function which returns bool depending on toggle status (addition or removal of item). Implementation:

```
$rootScope.toggleSelect = function(item) {
    var itemIndex = false;

    //find item index if existing in selectedItems array
    for(var i = 0; i < $rootScope.selectedItems.length; i++) {
      if($rootScope.selectedItems[i].name === item.name) {
        itemIndex = i;
      }
    }

    //Add to array if not exists
    if(itemIndex === false) {
      $rootScope.selectedItems.push(item);
    }
    //Remove if item exists
    else {
      $rootScope.selectedItems.splice(itemIndex, 1);
    }

    //Return toggle status (item addition or removal)
    return (itemIndex === false);
};
```

[JS Bin example](http://jsbin.com/memevemaxe/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. That was my original thought as well, but lets say I'm coming from an area to edit a deck. I need the cards that the deck already had selected previously to display as selected from the available 200 cards.

Comment: Yeah, but then you have a flag for it? {name:'item1', selected:true}. And then we're back to the solution discussed in previous comments.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Just wanted to share the use-case for it in some preliminary mockups http://www.simpollsystems.com/deck Sorry for the slow loading, no minifying yet, just wanted to share.

Comment: is there any solution for angular  13 version